# How visa days are counted? (Malaysia)

Tags: visas, malaysia, visa-runs

I have a 30 days stamped on my passport, currently I can't get my head around on how those days are counted.

Quintessentially, are the visa days counted the day one gets the stamp, or the day after one gets it?

I arrived on the 20th of May, I figured that I will either have to leave on the 18th June 2016 or the 19th June 2016.  But in my gut I would rather stick to the former.

I couldn't find any info to this regard, probably even having conflicting information.

Thanks for your ASAP answers.

Comment: ...1...2...3...4...5...no?

Answer (score 4):

In-country days are counted as calendar days not 24 hour periods. The day immigration stamps your passport starts the count. It doesn't matter what time you enter, be it 1 am or 11:59 pm, that arrival day is counted as one of your 30.

The allowable stay ends at 11:59 pm on the 30th day (18 June in your specific example).

This in-country 'clock' revolves around when immigration stamps you into or out of the country, so one could conceivably fly on day 31 at 4 am, as long as they cleared immigration before midnight.  But in countries like the USA where there are no exit formalities, then your clock stops at takeoff, so you need to fly out on the last day.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Pic - Sample of a  **VISIT PASS**  in a passport page. Includes the Return (or Outbound Air ticket sighted) and noted in the immigration stamp.

1. The day one enters Malaysia is taken as DAY 1. Must exit before the 30th Day or be regarded as "Overstay". Overstay in Malaysia is a Criminal Offense under Immigration and Civil Laws. Overstay even 1 day is **overstayed**.
2. It is prudent for a tourist to planned a 28 days visit to avoid breaking Immigration Laws. There is no excuse for missing flights, that it why a return ticket is compulsory as **one** of the minimum requirements for entry into Malaysia. Malaysian counters at Airports or Land Border Checkpoints are not allowed to collect any fines or moneys. Any overstay will have to go to the nearest IMI office/centers to pay fines. You would not be able to board the flight out of the country even for 1 day overstay.
3. There is no such thingy as "Visa Days" in Malaysia. A visa is to **enter** and **Visit Pass** (as shown in the above pic) is stamped into the passport pages to allow the tourist to live in Malaysia for a specific period of time. Please take serious notes that the "visa" systems in Malaysia, Singapore and Thailand is different from most of other EU countries.

Answer (score 0):

EDITED

By **Sunday,  June  19,  2016 at 00:00** you should leave Malaysia.
Which means **June 18** is the last day till **23:59**.

Comment: Are you sure about that? Day number 1 is normally day of entry

Comment: I use this small tool http://www.easysurf.cc/ndate1.htm , enter your entry date, add 30 (for my case I added 90), then the result is that day when you should leave.

Comment: Look on google images for entry stamps for places that give you 30 day entry and stamp date of exit. They typically are date of entry + 29 days

Comment: I've updated my answer.